# How to set the basepath of dompdf in a laravel 5.2 application

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I'm using laravel-dompdf ( https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ) to generate pdfs out of views. However I don't get how I can call the **set_base_path** function to correctly set the public path.

Without this I'm not able to load my css file...

I use the Facade like this

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', compact('data'));

return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

And require my css in my view like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pdf.css" />
```

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/pdf.css" />` It works for me.

Comment: I've not used laravel-dompdf, but ... have you tried `$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_base_path('/path/to/content/directory')`?

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt throw an error, however it's still not working... to fix it i just included it inline as within <style> tags

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the public path you can just call

```
{{URL::to('/')}}
```

or if you want to access to the asset path you should call

```
{{ URL::asset('assets/img/demo.jpg') }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I wanted to call the set_base_pah method of dompdf and not link to urls. Dompdf will not accept a relative url